# Delphi Shellexcute and windows run as option

Tags: delphi, runas

My computer is a part of company domain, 
I want to use the ShellApi's shellexcute function to run windows files with a given username and password (run as like), is it possible to include them in the function's parameters?

Comment: @jeff Once upon a time the [faq] wasn't as forthcoming as it appears to be now. Thanks for pointing out that it is better now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`CreateProcessAsUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and  [`LogonUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions or, more directly, use the [`CreateProcessWithLogon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

By the way, all these functions are declared in the `JwaWinBase` unit which is part of the [JEDI API Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/)